# Angular template not displaying the scope value in html

Tags: javascript, templates, angularjs, angular-routing

I have a $stateprovider setup as show below. I have issues in displaying content in the product.html page. The problem is the resolved 'title', which after being sent to the controller, and set on $scope, does not display in the template.

```
$stateProvider
          .state('main', {
            templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
            url: ""
          })
          .state('billing', {
            url: "/billing",
            controller: 'BillingCtrl',
            views: {
              "":{
                templateUrl: 'views/billing/billing.html'
              },
              "cart@billing":{
                templateUrl: 'views/billing/cart.html',
                controller: 'CartCtrl'
              },
              "products@billing":{
                templateUrl: 'views/billing/products.html',
                controller: 'ProductCtrl',
                resolve: {title: function(){return 'Hello'}} 
              }
            }
          });
```

The controller is

```
app.controller('ProductCtrl', function($scope, title){
    $scope.title = title;
});
```

And the template is

```
<div ui-view class="col-6">
    <h3>The test is {{title}}</h3>
</div>
```

On the browser it displays as

```
The test is {{title}}
```

In the chrome developer tool I can see the title getting the value of "Hello", but I can't understand why it's not resolving, even though it looks like a very silly bug.

Could I be making any silly mistake?

Comment: Damn! removing ui-view attribute from the template did the trick!